# Problem with understanding if two events are disjoint.

Tags: probability

I have a bit of an understanding problem. An Urn has $10$ balls; $6$ red, $3$ blue and $1$ green ball. A ball is chosen at random from the Urn and then returned. This is done $3$ times. The probability that with each pick, the colour of the ball is different is defined as the event $A$. $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{108}{1000}$. Let $B$ be the event that the first ball is red. Determine $\mathbb{P}(B^c | A)$.

Here is what I am confused with. I know that I have to use the following equation:

$$\mathbb{P}(B^c | A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B^c \cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(B^c)}$$

I know that if $B^c$ and $A$ are disjoint, then $\mathbb{P}(B^c \cap A) = \mathbb{P}(B^c) + \mathbb{P}(A)$ but if not, then: $\mathbb{P}(B^c \cap A) = \mathbb{P}(B^c) + \mathbb{P}(A)-\mathbb{P}(B^c \cup A)$. However, I am not sure if $A$ and $B^c$ are disjoint, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: By definition of conditioning: $\Bbb P(B^c\mid A)=\dfrac{\Bbb P(B^c\cap A)}{\Bbb P(A)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the terminology.

- disjoint means $$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$$ **and not** $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)$$
- independance means $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

As for your problem, given events are independant since nothing changes for the second and third time since we are returning balls.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. So then $\mathbb{P}(B^c | A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B^c \cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(B^c)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B^c)\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B^c)}=\mathbb{P}(A)$? Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: The *draws* are independent, *not* the events $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of conditioning $$\mathsf P(B^c\mid A)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B^c\cap A)}{\mathsf P(A)}$$

$A$ is the event that three independent draws result in three distinct colours.

$B$ is the event that the first ball is red.

These are clearly not disjoint, as they may both occur.  They may not be independent, as knowing that a red ball is drawn amongst the first three draws may have an influence on the expectation that it was drawn on the very first.  Therefore you should evaluate $\mathsf P(B^c\cap A)$ from the model.

---

You know that $\mathsf P(A) =\tfrac{108}{1000}$, which is $\tfrac{6\times 3\times 1}{10^3}{\times} 3!$ ... being the probability of obtaining red, blue, and green in three separate draws times the ways to arrange those draws.

You may use similar reasoning to determine $\mathsf P(B^c\cap A)$.